# Treating a collection of pointers to instances of a derived class as if they were the parent class

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, covariance

(This question has probably been answered before, and I can find *similar* questions, but nothing that I can apply to my situation. Links to relevant questions are of course appreciated.)

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to do:

```
    #include <vector>

    class Abstract
    {
    public:
        virtual std::vector<Abstract *> children() = 0;
    };

    class Concrete : public Abstract
    {
    public:
        std::vector<Abstract *> children() override {return std::vector<Abstract *>();} 
/* This returns an empty vector. What should actually go here, to return the actual children? */
    private:
        std::vector<Concrete *> m_children;
    };

    void doSomething(Abstract *a)
    {

    }

    int main()
    {
        Concrete c;

        for(auto& object : c.children())
            doSomething(object);
    }
```

In other words, my Concrete objects own instances of their own class as children. Other code wants to treat them as their Abstract base class. I can think of a few ways to achieve this, but I'm struggling to find an elegant one. It'd be nice if my classes supported iteration, but I can't get it to work with virtual abstract functions. I tried this:

(in Abstract)

```
virtual std::vector<const Abstract *>::const_iterator begin() const = 0;
virtual std::vector<const Abstract *>::const_iterator end() const = 0;
virtual std::vector<Abstract *>::iterator begin() = 0;
virtual std::vector<Abstract *>::iterator end() = 0;
```

, but what do I do in Concrete::begin() (where m_ children is declared as

```
m_children std::vector<Concrete *>
```

)? I began thus:

```
    std::vector<const Abstract *>::const_iterator it;
    Abstract *first = *m_children.begin();
```

... thinking that I might be able to have "it" point to the first instance in my vector. Here's where I'm stumped.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Why not store `std::vector<Abstract*> ` instead of std::vector<Concrete*>`?

Comment: Are you sure `children` should not return a `const&`?

Comment: Or even better with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Abstract>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Abstract>>`. Also don't forget to provide a virtual destructor `virtual ~Abstract() {}` in the `Abstract` class.

Comment: @ juanchopanza: Good question, the reason is that I have many classes that are derived from Abstract, and I don't want to litter them with casts when they perform operations on themselves and their children.

Comment: @Leander There's usually no need for casting, if the abstract interface is designed properly.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I'm working on a game, and I will probably not use smart pointers for this part of the code. I know that casting is not needed if everything is academically correct, but I have other considerations too.

Comment: Well, it looks like your design is broken. But you can use a [`boost transform iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to generate iterators that de-reference to one type from iterators that de-reference to another one.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the pointer, will check it out. So I take it that stl containers/iterators don't directly support what I'm trying to do, which is pretty much what I wanted to know. (I won't go into the whole design thing - I feel my design is suitable for what I'm doing).

Comment: [A bag of apples is *still* not a bag of fruit](https://www.google.com/search?q="a+bag+of+apples+is+not+a+bag+of+fruit").

Comment: This is the kind of discussion I did not want to get into. I guess I could have phrased my question differently. Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11,

```
return { begin(vec), end(vec) };
```

will convert a vec of concrete pointers to a vector of abstract.  It is that easy.

In C++03 you'd have to explicitly call the constructor and use `.begin` instead of the free function.

A casting iterator that takes iterators-to-concrete and produces iterators-to-abstract can be written, either via boost or manually, then a range of said retirned.

Type erasing the iterators so they are merely 'generic iterators to `abstract*`' can be done, either with boost or without.  This adds overhead (which could be substantial if not done carefully), and should only be entertained if the above two options are proven problematic, and this is demonstrated to fix the problem in actual tests.